# И еще по этимологии: "лад", "ладить" и "ладонь"

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

"Лад", "ладить" и "ладонь" - однокоренные слова? И, если да, то какое отношение слово "ладонь" имеет к первым двум понятиям?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово **ладонь** не родственно словам **лад** и **ладить**.

В рус. словарях **ЛАДОНЬ** отмечается с нач. XVIII в. По происхождению представляет собой звуков. видоизменение др.-рус. слова *долонь* — тожд. (ср. укр. *долόня*). В нем переставлены слоги *доло(нь) > лодо(нь)*. Далее в результате аканья, закрепленного в 
написании данного слова, или же, возможно, вследствие сближения этого слова **по народн. этимол.** с сущ. лад (ср. ладушки, ладошки) нач. слог *ло-* изменился в *ла-*. Др.-рус. *долонь* развилось из праслав. *dolnь с изменением -ol- между согласными в полногласное сочетание -оло- (ср. ст.-сл.* длань*, польск. dłon — тожд.). Праслав.* dоlnь образовано с пом. предметного суф. -nь- от и.-е. корня *dol-/*dal- «низ», «углубление». Ему родственны: гот. dal «долина»; греч. tholos «пещера».

Что касается слов **ЛАД** и **ЛАДИТЬ**, то их родство не вызывает сомнений, но достоверной этимологии у них нет. Предполагают родство с гот. *lеtan* "пускать" или с *лагода*.

Comment: Кажется, Ладо - это одно из славянских божеств?

Comment: Божеств с именами Ладо и Лада некоторые ученые называют плодом «кабинетной мифологии». О.Н.Трубачёв трактует слово в контексте слав. терминов родства: прасл. *lada восходит к и.-е. *aldh- «выросший, зрелый». Т.о., первичным значением славянского слова явл. «старший, муж, мужчина» (ср. Ладо - еще и звательная форма, обращение к возлюбленному в русском фольклоре, в «Слове о полку Игореве»). Перенесение этого слова на женщину — вторично. Но тут не место обсуждать этот вопрос. Можно только с уверенностью сказать, что имена эти родственны словам "лад", "ладить".

Comment: **olsa** пишет:

> По происхождению представляет собой
> звуков. видоизменение др.-рус. слова
> долонь — тожд. (ср. укр. долбня).

*Долбня*, *довбня* -- это разговорное, грубоватое или, точнее, простоватое выражение. Что-то вроде русского "ручища". А литературное слово ещё ближе к старославянскому -- "*долоня*".

Comment: Спасибо за реплику! Я написала так, как в словаре Цыганенко. Мне слово "долбня" резануло слух. И после вашего комментария я думаю, что при сканировании текста "долόня" распозналось как "долбня" (знак ударения слился с буквой О). Исправляю :-)